# Writing a 32-bit register to 32 pins as fast as possible in Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due

**Problem:**

- I'm using Due's QDEC function to decode a 32bit quadrature encoder.
- I need to pipe out the counter value as fast as possible to another instrument's DIO.
- The rear strip is selected as digital output because it's easy to slap an IDC connector on it.

```
#define QA 2
#define QB 13
const unsigned int mask_QA = digitalPinToBitMask(QA);
const unsigned int mask_QB = digitalPinToBitMask(QB);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200); 
    delay(100);
   
    // QDEC block
    REG_PIOB_PDR = mask_QA;     // activate peripheral function 
    REG_PIOB_ABSR |= mask_QA;   // choose peripheral option B   
    REG_PIOB_PDR = mask_QB;
    REG_PIOB_ABSR |= mask_QB;  
   
    REG_PMC_PCER0 = (1<<27);                                // activate clock for TC0 (PID27)
    REG_TC0_CMR0 = (1 << 0) | (1 << 2) | (1<<8) | (1<<10);  // config clock
    REG_TC0_BMR = (1<<9)|(1<<8)|(1<<12);                    // activate QDEC   
    REG_TC0_CCR0 = 5;                                       // enable the clock and reset counter

    //PIO BLOCK
    // mask write, the rear strip of Arduino Due
    REG_PIOA_OWER = 0x0018c808; // A 7 14 15 19 20
    REG_PIOB_OWER = 0x04204000; // B 14 21 26
    REG_PIOC_OWER = 0x000FF3FE; // C 1-9 12-19
    REG_PIOD_OWER = 0x0000064F; // D 0 1 2 3 6 9 10
}   
void loop() {

  // data write
  REG_PIOA_ODSR = REG_TC0_CV0;
  REG_PIOB_ODSR = REG_TC0_CV0;
  REG_PIOC_ODSR = REG_TC0_CV0;
  REG_PIOD_ODSR = REG_TC0_CV0;
}
```

- This code is untested as I don't have access to the hardware right now.
- Basically 4 bit masks (for PIO ABCD) are created to map the 32bit `REG_TC0_CV0` onto the rear strip.

**Requirement:**

- [Priority] As little **delay** as possible, every clock cycle matters.
- [Secondary] Output bandwidth should match the update rate of `REG_TC0_CV0`, which I didn't manage to find in the manual. The output should also provide a latch for the receiving equipment to sync sampling.

**Question:**

- Would disabling peripheral functions for all 32 pins on the rear strip interfere with the core functionality that this program depends on (timer/counter etc) ?
- Are there other ways that can accomplish this faster ?
- I would like to use the main CPU tread for serial interface. It is possible to attach the four ODSR writing instructions to a timer ISR so it does not interfere with `void loop()`?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please post a link to the quadrature encoder .... it actually makes no sense that it would require a 32 bit interface

Comment: @jsotola The quadrature encoder is from a scientific-grade brushless linear motor. I don't know the exact part number but the linear motor has the precision of 20000 counts/mm, and the max travel of the motor is 220mm. So the top count is 4400000, which requires at least 23 bits. Also the output format of REG_TC0_CV0 is 32 bits.

Comment: Define as fast as possible? once per second, a 100,000,000 times a second, both are possible but there is a upper limit to what you can do with a processor, additional hardware may be needed. More Information Please?

Comment: @Gil Thanks for your interests in my question. I have updated the question to better define "fast".

Comment: @Gil 100MHz possible ? I thought the MCK is 84MHz. However that's irrelevant as the output should be attached to ISR for when ```REG_TC0_CV0``` became available.